# Is it possible "unpivot" table with SQL?

Tags: sql, unpivot

I have a table:

```
id  amount  Y2016   Y2017   Y2018
1   100             1       1
2   200         
3   300     2       
4   400     2       3   
5   500                     1
```

and need to unpivot it and made some calculation
Result table (multiply "amount" on years data):

```
id  year    amount
1   Y2017   100
1   Y2018   100
3   Y2016   600
4   Y2016   800
4   Y2017   1200
5   Y2018   500
```

Is it possible? And how?

Comment: You should tag your questions -- in general -- with the database you are using.

Comment: Actualy it just add-in for Excel that makes run SQL for excel tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way uses `union all`

```
select id, 'Y2016' as year, Y2016 * amount as amount
from t
where Y2016 is not null
union all
select id, 'Y2017' as year, Y2017 * amount as amount
from t
where Y2017 is not null
union all
select id, 'Y2018' as year, Y2018 * amount as amount
from t
where Y2018 is not null;
```

There are other methods (some depending on the database).  But for your data, this should be fine.

Comment: if I have planty Y2XXX fields?

Comment: @FFire . . . You can continue adding subqueries -- a spreadsheet can help in constructing the query, if you want.